# NSTemporaryDirectory() without blank spaces

Tags: swift, cocoa

```
guard let tempDirURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent("MyAppStuff.xxx") else {
        return nil
    }
```

My question is: will be tempDirURL.path always without blank spaces in the middle?

EDIT, from documentation:[image]

Comment: Why not write code that is resilient to having spaces in the path? You're not really guaranteed anything in particular about the temporary directory path. With that said, if it doesn't have spaces now, it likely won't because of issues that would crop up like this and legacy apps might not handle it properly. So do everyone a favor and try to handle spaces correctly :).

Comment: Sorry but the best favor I can do is accept an answer to my question, pleas don't post comment if you have no idea. I'm working on a app that for a policy require to dump some binaries. After patching some location of that binary this one is flashed to a device from a compiled framenwork they give me. That is a contract by a customer. If I want handle withe space surely I have no problem, just don't use NSAppleScript, because any other methods are fine like write an helper tool that in this case is unwanted, to do things with elevated privileges. Also they did not pay for that.

Comment: Edited the first post on why I need that. The question is simple, just I cant take a look on Apple's source and nothing is on the documentation about that (correct me If I'm wrong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API contract does not guarantee that the path returned by `NSTemporaryDirectory()` will not contain spaces; therefore you cannot assume that it will not. You will need to account for the possibility that the path could contain any and all characters allowed by the file system.

Comment: GNUStep-NSTemporaryDirectory() was adding the user name to that path (so it's obvious that can happen), but that does not happens in Cocoa witch is different (see here: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/discuss-gnustep/2001-04/msg00032.html). It's also obvious that in Cocoa things are different and their example (see my new edit on the question) are just "foregone".

Comment: @Mike97 It doesn't happen in Cocoa *right now*. Anything which is not promised, however, is free to change at any time. The location of `NSTemporaryDirectory()` has, in fact, changed in the past; it used to be inside `/tmp`, whereas now it is in `/var/folders`. It could change again in the future; you should write your code in such a way that it will not break if that happens.

Comment: strictly is not a matter of a good code, just I hate AppleScript that is not a language (or is?). I found a way w/o writing an helper (which I have one to reuse .. but isnt good for them..). This is a Mac variant of a Windows tool the customer have to program some devices... but pricing does not allow me to lose time with AppleScript, so I'll inform of a possible bug or just fall back to /private/tmp, where no one will steal their precious temporary files (their fears) since also NSTemporaryDirectory() isn't a secret anyway and in addition looks persistent for 3 days.

Comment: If they don't want prying eyes to look at their temporary files, you should not use /private/tmp. `NSTemporaryDirectory()` may not be a secret, but it is per-user, and randomly generated. Programs running under other users will not be able to access its contents.